# loop though json response laravel 5.6

Tags: json, laravel

How can i loop though an json response?
I need to loop though eg. **$request->device_id**.
Then i could save each value returned. *(I need to loop though most of the requests)*.

```
    return response()->json([
        'data' => Device::create([
            'device_id' => $request->device_id,
            'hub_id' => $request->hub_id,
            'name' => $request->name,
           ....
        ]),
    ]);
```

json response looks like:

[image]

Comment: do you want to loop through response or request?

Comment: through the request since there is the data, i need to access the data.

Answer (score 0):

According to Laravel documentation

> When sending JSON requests to your application, you may access the JSON data via the input method as long as the Content-Type header of the request is properly set to application/json. You may even use "dot" syntax to dig into JSON arrays:

```
$name = $request->input('user.name');
```

however you can use `json_decode()` function to convert JSON to PHP array. then loop through the array using `foreach()`

Comment: I can access the values when i do `dd($request->device_id),` i get back the values.
How can i loop the requests inside this response ? Btw i would need 6/7 foreach loops, how to do this smarter ?

Comment: is _device_id_ the only input you want to loop through?

Comment: No i need to loop though 7 inputs that would be 7 foreach loops how to do this smarter ?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have store all the devices into variable name $devices.

```
$devices = Device::all();

foreach($devices as $device) {
    $deviceIds = json_decode($device->devicez_id);
    foreach($deviceIds as $deviceId) {
      //you will get device id on variable name (deviceId)
    }
}
```

Comment: My problem is that i want to store inputs, i have not stored them yet. I would have 7 inputs that would need foreach loos how to do this smarter and save all inputs at once.